# Drupal: The selected file intersection.png could not be uploaded

Tags: drupal

I don't understand why I get this error when I upload images...

The selected file intersection.png could not be uploaded. The file is not a known image format.

It is just a png file, and the problem came when I moved the website on the server. On localhost everything was perfect.

1) I've deleted the "files" folder and created it again with a php script (to make the server the owner)
2) drupal automatically creates 2 folders into it (imagecache and temp) so I assume it has the privilegies to write into it.
3) I've changed the temporary folder in Settings > Filesystem from "/tmp" to "temp", since I got an error before (probably the /tmp folder on the server is not writable by drupal

thanks

Comment: I tried another image format: The selected file logo.jpeg could not be uploaded. The file is not a known image format. I've set the temporary folder back to /tmp, still nothing...

Comment: The Web server is Microsoft-IIS/6.0. Is ImageChache not compatible ?
Please tell me there is solution otherwise it is a bad problem :(

Comment: imagecache will work after uploading. so your first problem is creating file first in tmp folder, next in files folder. Check your permissions again...

Comment: I just realized the problem is that rewriting is not working and I cannot use cleanURLs. I don't have access to server configuration file, is there any way I can enable rewriting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The rewrite module is not enabled on my IIS server, so I had to change a line of code inside the imagecache.module to add "index.php?q=

return url($GLOBALS['base_url'] . '/index.php?q=' . file_directory_path() .'/imagecache/'. $presetname .'/'. $path, $args);

Answer (score 1):

http://drupal.org/project/transliteration I think this module help me in my problem related this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There's a known problem with Drupal 6.15 and IIS (see http://drupal.org/node/419734). If you're on 6.15, try backing down to 6.14 until a fix is completed.

Comment: hi, thanks for link. I will defintely keep it in mind. However, I just realize rewriting is not working on the server, and I cannot use cleanURLs, which are required by imagecache module. So... is this something I have to fix before, right ? Can you give me any tip ?